# How to limit file extension in Eclipse RAP FileDialog

Tags: file-upload, file-extension, eclipse-rap

I am using `RAP Target 2.3` + Incubator's `FileDialog` to upload file from browser.

Is there any way to limit selection only specific file extensions ?